# Coefficient of variation of log-Gamma distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, gamma-distribution, logarithm, coefficient-of-variation

If I have a Gamma distributed random variable $y$:

\begin{equation}
    y \sim Gamma(\alpha, \beta)
\end{equation}

which has coefficient of variation $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}}$, then what would be the coefficient of variation of $x$, defined as:

\begin{equation}
    x = \ln(y)
\end{equation}

? I have found some information on the log-Gamma distribution, but it isn't clear to me whether the coefficient of variation is just $\ln( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}})$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The logarithm of $Y$ has momentgenerating function
\begin{align}
M(t) &= Ee^{t\ln Y}
\\ &= E(Y^t)
\\ &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}y^{\alpha + t - 1}e^{-\lambda t}dt
\\ &= \frac{\lambda^\alpha\Gamma(\alpha+t)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\lambda^{\alpha+t}}
\\ &= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+t)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\lambda^t}
\end{align}
and cumulant generating function
\begin{align}
K(t)=\ln M(t)=\ln\Gamma(\alpha + t)-\ln\Gamma(\alpha)-t\ln\lambda.
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
  E(\ln Y)&=K'(0)=\psi_0(\alpha)-\ln\lambda,
\\ \operatorname{Var}(\ln Y)&=K''(0)=\psi_1(\alpha),
\end{align}
and
$$
 \operatorname{CV}(\ln Y)=\frac{\sqrt{\psi_1(\alpha)}}{\psi_0(\alpha)-\ln\lambda},
$$
where $\psi_0$ and $\psi_1$ are the di- and trigamma functions.